# MATLAB Morse Code diff and find functions

Tags: matlab, find, token, diff

We are trying to write a function that takes arr and counts how many 0's and 1's appear in sequence. The output should be a 2D array where column 1 is how many appear in sequence and column 2 is which token it is (0 or 1).  Our function below

```
function [token] = tokenizeSignal(arr)
  matA = diff(find(diff([log_vector;-1])));
  addA = zeros(size(matA, 1),1);
  matA = [matA, addA];

  matB = diff(find(diff([log_vector;0])));
  addB = ones(size(matB, 1), 1);
  matB = [matB, addB];

  [nRowsA, nCols] = size(matA);
  nRowsB = size(matB, 1);

  AB = zeros(nRowsA + nRowsB, nCols);
  AB(1:2:end, :) = matA;
  AB(2:2:end, :) = matB;

  token = AB;
```

works with

```
arr = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0];
```

but nothing else because it adds random integers into the matrix. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Adding a non trivial example of what you want would help

Comment: How do you want your result to depend from `arr` if you don't use it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that takes any array arr and produces what you want:

```
% input checking/processing
% ... convert the input into a column vector
arr = arr(:);
% ... check that the input is nonempty and numeric
if ~isnumeric(arr), error('Bad input'); end
if isempty(arr), error('Bad input'); end

% determine the starting indices of each sequence in arr
I = [1 ; find(diff(arr)) + 1];

% determine the values of each of these sequences
values = arr(I);

% determine the length of each of these sequences
value_counts = [diff(I) ; length(arr) - max(I) + 1];

% produce the output
token = [value_counts, values];
```